# How to install LDR-Importer Add-on?

Tags: add-on, installation

I'd like to install [**LDR-Importer**](https://github.com/le717/LDR-Importer/releases) in order to import LDraw .dat and .ldr models into Blender. Unfortunately the script comes with no installation documentation. Where should I unpack the github archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can save it at a logical place for you, you don't have to unzip it. In blender you open the user preferences --> add-ons--> install from file, locate the file and than check the file.

[image]